# OpenGL orthographic projection

Tags: opengl, graphics

In the description of gluOrtho2d they say it's like glOrtho with near=-1 and far=1.

1. Why is near behind the viewer.
2. Why does the matrix described
       here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml have the
       Z-axis inverted?

Comment: If you plug these values into `glOrtho`, [2][2] = -1, and [2][3] = (tz) = 0, you have a very simple transform. It effectively does nothing to the Z coordinate, except change the sign for depth requirements.

Comment: What the heck is `glOrtho2d`?

Comment: @genpfault: Most likely `gluOrtho2d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As the name would imply, gluOrtho2d is meant for drawing things where the depth coordinate doesn't really matter.  It's set up so you can send 2-component verts to the gpu and the depth just defaults to 0.  In this case it makes sense to have a projection where 0 is right in between the near/far planes so you don't have to worry about it.  It's worth mentioning that in an orthographic projection the idea of being "behind" the viewer loses some of its meaning anyway because the distance from the viewer to the object has no affect on the projection other than choosing whether or not to draw it at all.

2) Probably because in OpenGL space, the NEGATIVE Z-axis is into the screen, so if glOrtho didn't negate you'd always have to pass in negative values for near and far.  Which would be a little weird I guess.

Comment: The Z-axis is comes *out* of the screen. It's a right-handed coordinate system.

Comment: Yes...drawing has right hand coordinate whereas projection itself has a left hand coordinate system (it's still beyond me why that's the case). However, do you guys happen to know why?

Comment: Also, why would anyone care if 0 is between near and far? why can't it just be near at 0?

Comment: @Roveris You wouldn't want to be drawing right at the near clip plane because nearly everything in OpenGL winds up as floating point -- this means exact comparisons (0 == 0?) aren't reliable.  In other words, the near clip plane would somewhat randomly chop stuff out.